# Trocar cor do menu tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, menu, background-color

Quero trocar a cor do Menu do tkinter para por exemplo preto, existe algo como:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

menu = Menu(root, background='red')

menu.add_cascade(label='test1')

menu.add_cascade(label='test2')

menu.add_cascade(label='test3')


root.config(menu=menu)

root.mainloop()
```

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHSKT.png)

Answer (score 1):

Neste caso basta fazer assim:

```
root.configure(background='black')
```

caso queira outra cor basta trocar o parametro de 'black' para a cor desejada.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Essa não é uma solução para o problema, pois ai eu estaria mudando a cor do fundo da minha janela e eu desejo mudar a cor do fundo do menu